# Find the generating function for given series

Tags: generating-functions

I have this given assignment, and I need a couple of hints to get me started since I don't know how to do this. 
what is the generating function for the given series: $\{ 1,3,5,7,9 \}$?

Comment: Let $a_n=2n-1$.

Comment: I see your solution is right. But in an answer i cant just write that ( i think). It's more like i need a general solution-method for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Ancient art called observation, and knowledge of number line aka something which looks like the series $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ might come handy at times. Rest, and a general solution method is a mystery yet to be solved.

Comment: The generating function $g$ for the (finite) sequence $(1,3,5,7,9)$ is the function defined by$$g(s)=1+3s+5s^2+7s^3+9s^4.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* sequences whose first five terms are 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9. As an example, consider $$a(n) = 5 - \frac{n}{20} (n - 3) (n - 6) ((n - 3)^2 + 4) \text{ for } n=1, \ldots, 5.$$
For other possibilities, you can check The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which has [400+ results](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C9) for this, including the popular [a(n) = 2n+1](https://oeis.org/A005408) similar to the one mentioned in the comments.